# Find missing transactions for Client IDs in last 7 days in table where there should be one transaction per day per client

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with unique Client IDs and date timestamp field. Each client should have a transaction record in this table every day as long as they have an "active" status. But sometimes the source of the table data, a file, is missing a transaction record for 1 or 2 clients for a day or two, but then the client comes back on the file. I want to run a query every Monday to find any client ID that was missing transaction records in the last 7 days but then had transaction records populate after missing days, or never came back on the file.

Here is an example of what the data looks like when a client ID has no transaction record for a day or two but has transaction records after that.

SAMPLE DATA

| client_id | record_timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 02/06/2024 5:00:44.940 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/09/2024 5:01:45.203 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/10/2024 5:00:38.530 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/11/2024 6:00:38.737 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/12/2024 5:00:41.257 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/13/2024 5:01:30.007 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/05/2024 5:00:44.940 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/06/2024 5:02:18.940 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/07/2024 5:52:27.540 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/08/2024 5:03:28.940 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/09/2024 5:07:53.090 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/11/2024 6:02:35.607 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/12/2024 5:02:42.237 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/13/2024 5:03:28.970 AM |

DESIRED SAMPLE RESULT

| client_id | record_timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 02/06/2024 5:00:44.940 AM |
| 123456789 | NULL |
| 123456789 | NULL |
| 123456789 | 02/09/2024 5:01:45.203 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/10/2024 5:00:38.530 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/11/2024 6:00:38.737 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/12/2024 5:00:41.257 AM |
| 123456789 | 02/13/2024 5:01:30.007 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/06/2024 5:02:18.940 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/07/2024 5:52:27.540 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/08/2024 5:03:28.940 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/09/2024 5:07:53.090 AM |
| 111222333 | NULL |
| 111222333 | 02/11/2024 6:02:35.607 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/12/2024 5:02:42.237 AM |
| 111222333 | 02/13/2024 5:03:28.970 AM |

I tried lead and lag functions, I tried CTEs, but I am not getting it quite right. Here is the last thing I was trying but I know the syntax and construction isn't correct.

```
SELECT
    client_id,
    received_date,
    CASE WHEN previous_date IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE previous_date END AS Missing_Record
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            client_id,
            CAST (record_timestamp AS DATE) AS received_date,
            LEAD (CAST (record_timestamp AS DATE), 1) OVER (ORDER BY CAST (record_timestamp AS DATE) DESC) AS previous_date
        FROM Client_Table
        WHERE CONVERT (VARCHAR (10),record_timestamp, 1) >= DATEADD (DAY,- 7,CONVERT (DATE,GETDATE ())) 
            AND CONVERT (VARCHAR (10),record_timestamp,1) < DATEADD (DAY,DATEDIFF (DAY,0,GETDATE ()),0)
    --btw last 7 days and yesterday
    )
    X
WHERE previous_date IS NULL
GROUP BY
   client_id,
    received_date,
    previous_date
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `CONVERT (VARCHAR (10),record_timestamp, 1) >= DATEADD...`? What datatype is `record_timestamp`? If its a datetime then compare it as a datetime.

Comment: @Dale K, I have been trying different formats in order to compare dates. This is why I am asking for help since I've been trying different things based on looking at various scenarios on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Dates, when stored correctly as a datetime, don't have a format (aside from the binary format), formatting is a display thing, and as soon as you format it you are comparing strings instead of dates. And you didn't answer why question, what datatype is it? (Alternatively post your table definition).

Comment: And if you create a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with your sample data and attempt you make it **much** easier for us to assist.

Comment: datatype is datetime

Comment: A common way to solve that issue is to have a calendar or tally table.

Comment: Tally table should be able to do the job. There isn't any `"date"` in the expected result beside the original `record_timestamp`

Comment: @Squirrel, Thank you so much for helping me with my 1st post on Stackoverflow. Dale K, thank you for letting me know the proper way to present a question. Squirrel, your solution worked great once I set up the index on the tally table. Thank for also showing me how to use Fiddle, I will use that going forward.

Comment: Yes. Index is important as mention by Dwain in that link. Quote `"If you create a permanent Tally table, it’s important to have a CLUSTERED INDEX (the PRIMARY KEY) on the single column that’s in the table for performance reasons."`

Answer (score 0):

A common way to return missing rows is to generate the expected list and then left join to your table.

For date related, a pre-generated calendar table will comes in handy. For this case, since there isn't any "date" in the required result other than the original `record_timestamp`, the query is simplify using just a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) or `GENERATE_SERIES` if you are using `SQL Server 2022+`

Here is the query using a tally table. Find the number of days different between current and next row using `lead()` window function. Then `cross join` to the tally table.

```
select client_id, 
       record_timestamp = case when t.n = 1 
                               then c.record_timestamp 
                               end
from   (
           select client_id, record_timestamp,
                  next_record_timestamp = lead(record_timestamp)
                                          over(partition by client_id
                                                   order by record_timestamp)
           from   Client_Table 
       ) c
       cross join tally t
where t.n >= 1 
and   t.n <= datediff(day, c.record_timestamp, c.next_record_timestamp)
order by client_id, 
         coalesce(c.record_timestamp, c.next_record_timestamp)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GIRKdDTm)

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, having null in the padding rows is pretty weird... they can't be sorted or anything with that.

Comment: True. That's why the `coalesce(....` expression in the `order by` to sort it. Other than that, there is not way to know which NULL row is related to which date

Comment: Yes I suspect OP has oversimplified... but hey ho... maybe they will let you know sometime :)

Comment: Please do accept it as answer if this resolved your issue